# Write to a file within Azure Function failing

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, plist

Currently, I am having my azure function (in python) dynamically write a a plist file to in order for an app to be downloaded through a browser on an IOS device. This works fine locally, but when it is published to Azure I get an internal server error 500 and it fails to write the file when the function is called. This is my code snippet:

```
pList = {
        'items': [
            {
                'assets': [
                    {
                        'kind': 'software-package',
                        'url': ipaUrl
                    },
                    {
                        'kind': 'display-image',
                        'needs-shine': False,
                        'url': imageUrl
                    }
                ],
                'metadata': {
                    'bundle-identifier': bundleName,
                    'bundle-version': f'{versionName} ({buildName})',
                    'kind': 'software',
                    'title': appName
                }
            }
        ]
    }
with open('list.plist', 'wb') as file:
    plistlib.dump(pList, file)
```

Any suggestions? I am not sure if functions supports reading / writing to files when deployed so that may be my issue.

Comment: There is a small local storage available to a running Function, so you'd need to ensure you write files there and they aren't too large. Otherwise, need to use some other storage like blob or mounted file share

Comment: Are you aware what directory this local storage would be available at? My plist files are 1kb so size is not an issue.

Comment: The path would be OS dependent -- it should be in docs or guides about working with files in Functions. Typically on a `D` drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files can be temporary, you could use the temporary storage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#temporary-files

You can also access the root folder - but dependent on the type OS.
https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder/

If you need to permanently store the files, best to link your app to storage account (blob storage). (either with output binding or in the SDK)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: Thank you. Using temp storage worked for me.